# Como faco para ler para ler esses números e somar todos sem ter que somar variável por variável tipo soma-la 60 vezes

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

```
Algoritmo "questionario"

Var Resposta: Caractere
Var soma,Nota: Inteiro

Inicio

Escreval("Questionario ENEM 2018
")

Escreval("1) Qual a capital do Brasil?")
Escreval("----------------------------")
Escreval("a) Brasilia")
Escreval("b) Acre")
Escreval("c) São Paulo")
Escreval("d) Amazônia")
Escreval("
Digite a resposta correta")
Leia (Resposta)

Se (Resposta="a") Entao
Escreval("Resposta Correta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-(+10)
Senao
Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-Nota+0
Fimse


//Questão 2//
Escreval("2) Qual a cidade maravilhosa?")
Escreval("----------------------------")
Escreval("a) Brasilia")
Escreval("b) Acre")
Escreval("c) São Paulo")
Escreval("d) Rio De Janeiro")
Escreval("
Digite a resposta correta")
Leia (Resposta)

Se (Resposta="d") Entao
Escreval("Resposta Correta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-(+10)
Senao
Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-(+0)
Fimse


//Questão 3//
Escreval("3) Qual a cidade maravilhosa?")
Escreval("----------------------------")
Escreval("a) Brasilia")
Escreval("b) Acre")
Escreval("c) São Paulo")
Escreval("d) Rio De Janeiro")
Escreval("
Digite a resposta correta")
Leia (Resposta)

Se (Resposta="d") Entao
Escreval("Resposta Correta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-(+10)
Senao
Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
Escreval("===================

")
Nota<-(+0)
Fimse


Escreval("Seu total de pontos foi de " ,  Nota)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Beatriz, boa noite

Verifiquei seu código e percebi que algumas operações não precisamos colocar e a somatória de nota não está correta.

Dica: Utilize a indentação, além de facilitar a leitura, irá facilitar a compreensão do código de quem for ler.

```
algoritmo "questionario"

var
   Resposta: Caractere
   soma, Nota: Inteiro

inicio
   //Importante inicializar com valor 0, caso contrário irá inicializar com valor aleatório
   nota <- 0

   Escreval("Questionario ENEM 2018")
   Escreval("1) Qual a capital do Brasil?")
   Escreval("----------------------------")
   Escreval("a) Brasilia")
   Escreval("b) Acre")
   Escreval("c) São Paulo")
   Escreval("d) Amazônia")
   Escreva("Digite a resposta correta: ")
   Leia (Resposta)

   Se (Resposta = "a") entao
      Escreval("Resposta Correta")
      Escreval("===================")
      Nota <- Nota + 10
   Senao
      //Caso a resposta seja falsa não é preciso incrementar, pois o valor continua 0
      Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
      Escreval("===================")
   Fimse

   //Questão 2//
   Escreval("2) Qual a cidade maravilhosa?")
   Escreval("----------------------------")
   Escreval("a) Brasilia")
   Escreval("b) Acre")
   Escreval("c) São Paulo")
   Escreval("d) Rio De Janeiro")
   Escreva("Digite a resposta correta: ")
   Leia (Resposta)

   Se (Resposta = "d") entao
      Escreval("Resposta Correta")
      Escreval("===================")
      Nota<- Nota + 10
   Senao
      Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
      Escreval("===================")
   Fimse

   //Questão 3//
   Escreval("3) Qual a cidade maravilhosa?")
   Escreval("----------------------------")
   Escreval("a) Brasilia")
   Escreval("b) Acre")
   Escreval("c) São Paulo")
   Escreval("d) Rio De Janeiro")
   Escreval("Digite a resposta correta")
   Leia (Resposta)

   Se (Resposta = "d") entao
      Escreval("Resposta Correta")
      Escreval("===================")
      Nota <- Nota + 10
   Senao
      Escreval("Resposta Incorreta")
      Escreval("===================")
   Fimse

   Escreval("Seu total de pontos foi de ", Nota)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Para somar mais números em vez de variável por variável, utilize a estrutura de repetição PARA FACA FIMPARA

Observe um exemplo abaixo:

```
algoritmo "Somar60vezes"
var
   soma, valor, contador, resultado: Inteiro

inicio

   Para contador <- 1 ate 60 faca
      Escreva("Informe o ", contador, "º valor para somar: ")
      Leia(valor)
      soma <- soma + valor
   FimPara

   resultado <- soma

   Escreva("A soma do valor é ", resultado)

fimalgoritmo
```

Para não ficar digitando 60 vezes, o visualg disponibiliza uma ferramenta que gera valores aleatórios, veja no campo destacado em vermelho, já o campo em amarelo você pode escolher o intervalo para gerar os valores aleatórios, neste caso irei gerar qualquer número que esteja entre 0 e 20
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]